# Getting Error "Number of distinct destination bucket ARNs cannot exceed 1" while setting up s3 cross account replication via cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I have a requirement to replicate objects present in bucket A to bucket B and C, bucket B is present in same account but in different region and bucket C is present in different AWS account.

I have tried to setup above requirement manually and I was able to do it, While trying to do via cloudformation I was getting an error as **"Number of distinct destination bucket ARNs cannot exceed 1"**
I have coded replication rule as shown below, whole code is being done by referring to AWS documentation.

```
ReplicationConfiguration:
  Role: !Ref S3RoleArn
  Rules:
    - Id: Rule1
      Destination:
        Bucket: "arn:aws:s3:::bucketB"
        StorageClass: STANDARD
      Status: Enabled
    - Id: Rule2
      Destination:
        Bucket: "arn:aws:s3:::bucketC"
        AccessControlTranslation:
           Owner: Destination
        Account: !Ref DestAccountId
        StorageClass: STANDARD
      Status: Enabled
```

First I have put the replication rule for bucketB which is in same account but in different region and it worked fine. Then I have written another rule for replication object from bucket A to bucketC. bucketC is present in different AWS account.

Answer (score 2):

To overcome this issue, I have to use Filter, Priority and DeleteMarkerReplication properties.

```
ReplicationConfiguration:
  Role: !Ref S3RoleArn
  Rules:
    - Id: Rule1
      Destination:
        Bucket: "arn:aws:s3:::bucketB"
        StorageClass: STANDARD
      Status: Enabled
      Priority: 1
        Filter:
          Prefix: ''
      DeleteMarkerReplication:
        Status: Enabled
    - Id: Rule2
      Destination:
        Bucket: "arn:aws:s3:::bucketC"
        AccessControlTranslation:
           Owner: Destination
        Account: !Ref DestAccountId
        StorageClass: STANDARD
      Status: Enabled
      Priority: 2
        Filter:
          Prefix: ''
      DeleteMarkerReplication:
        Status: Enabled
```

by using the above mentioned properties, I was able to successfully create the stack with the required replication rule.

Comment: Full description of the problem and solution here https://cloudkatha.com/resolved-number-of-distinct-destination-bucket-arns-cannot-exceed-1/